# Is there a method in kubernetes client replacing "kubectl port-forward" command

Tags: kubernetes

I need to forward port of one Kubernetes pods. One possible way is to execute kubectl command like bellow:

```
kubectl port-forward podm-resource-manager-56b9ccd59c-8pmdn 8080
```

Is there a way to achieve the same using python (for example python kubernetes-client)?

Answer (score 7):

The method [connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/release-9.0/kubernetes/docs/CoreV1Api.md#connect_get_namespaced_pod_portforward) is available in in the python kubernetes-client to do a port forward.

Comment: Unfortunately it and the stream wrapper are rather less than clearly documented, and they only appear to support exchanging GET or POST requests, not arbitrary TCP streams.

Answer (score 1):

The `kr8s` library [supports port forwarding](https://docs.kr8s.org/en/stable/examples/pod_operations.html#open-a-port-forward-and-communicate-with-the-pod).

This Python is equivalent to `kubectl port-forward`.

```py
from kr8s.objects import Pod

pod = Pod.get("podm-resource-manager-56b9ccd59c-8pmdn")
pod.portforward(8080, local_port=8080).run_forever()
```

You can also use a context manager if you want to interact with the port in Python.

```py
import requests
from kr8s.objects import Pod

pod = Pod.get("podm-resource-manager-56b9ccd59c-8pmdn")
with pod.portforward(remote_port=8080) as local_port:
    # Make an API request to the forwarded port
    resp = requests.get(f"http://localhost:{local_port}/foo/bar")
```

Or you can start the port forward as a background thread and continue doing other things in your Python code.

```py
from kr8s.objects import Pod

pod = Pod.get("podm-resource-manager-56b9ccd59c-8pmdn")
pf = pod.portforward(remote_port=8080, local_port=8080)
pf.start()  # Start the port forward in a background thread

# Your other code goes here

pf.stop()  # Optionally stop the port forward thread (it will exit with Python anyway)
```